# Python subprocess in a service

Tags: python, service, subprocess

In a python script that I run as a service, I need to launch a linux command.
Here is a simple python script, let's call it serviceTest.py :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["touch serviceTest"],shell:True)
```

Then I set-up the following service

```
[Unit]  
Description= test of a service launching a unix command  
[Service]  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/pythonScripts/serviceTest.py  
SyslogIdentifier=serviceTest  
User = pi  
Group = pi  
[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script works fine but the service cannot be run.

Would appreciate some help !
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "the service cannot be run"? What's your error? What did you expect to happen? What's actually happening?

Comment: wait `shell:True`? shouldnt it be `shell=True`? also try changing `["touch serviceTest"]` to `["touch", "serviceTest"]`

Comment: Typo: my code is actually shell=True.

Comment: The service cannot be run: meaning when I type systemctl status nameOfTheService I see that the service status is "failed"

Comment: probably says "failed" because the program exits immediately and it expects it to be a continuously running program. Try putting `while True: time.sleep(10)`  (`import time`) so that it'll just idle for forever (after the subprocess command)

Comment: @Macattack: NOP, this doesn't fix the pb. Status is still " Active: failed (Result: exit-code)" Thanks nevertheless.